# JComboBox not opening in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have created a table where in a cell of each row a combo box is displayed. I have used the following two classes as cell editor and cell renderer respectively. Somehow when the table is displayed, every combo box in a cell doesn't open when it's clicked. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance

```
public class CellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CellEditor(String[] items) {
    super(new JComboBox(items));
}
}

public class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
/****/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
    super(items);
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    if (isSelected) {
        this.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        this.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        this.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }        
    this.setSelectedItem(value);// Select the current value      
    return this;
}
}
```

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please!

Comment: Why are you extending the DefaultCellEditor? There is no need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please reads [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)'s tutorial, there are [Editors and Renderers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), some examples on this Forum (inc AutoCompleted JComboBox in the JTable) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm) or [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html)

but basically is your question about, (check if you set that)

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col == someInt) {
        return true;
    } else if (col == TableColumnsStartsWithZero) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```